# C# Async and Await flow

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to understand  async and await flow . Started looking at code from
[John Atten's blog](http://johnatten.com/2015/01/04/asp-net-understanding-owin-katana-and-the-middleware-pipeline/) about Owin and Katana . While trying to look at the execution steps I found few steps in the flow (Steps 9 and 16),  which I am not able to understand as to why the execution  will traverse.

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
namespace KatanaConsole
{
    //use an alias for OWIN APPFunc
    using AppFunc= Func<IDictionary<string,object>,Task>;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var uri = "http://localhost:8080";

            using ( WebApp.Start<StartUp>(uri))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Web Server started on port 2323");
                 Console.WriteLine("Server Started; Press enter to Quit");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class StartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
        var firstMiddleware= new Func<AppFunc,AppFunc>(FirstMiddleware);
        var secondMiddleware = new Func<AppFunc, AppFunc>(SecondMiddleware);

        appBuilder.Use(firstMiddleware);
        appBuilder.Use(secondMiddleware);

        }


        public AppFunc FirstMiddleware(AppFunc next)
        {

            AppFunc appFunc = async environment =>
            {
                IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1> Middleware:1 ->  Hello from X1</h1>");
                await next.Invoke(environment);
            };
            return appFunc;
        }

        public AppFunc SecondMiddleware(AppFunc next)
        {

            AppFunc appFunc = async (IDictionary<string, object> environment) =>
            {
                IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1> Middleware:2 ->  Hello from X2</h1>");
                await next.Invoke(environment);
            };
            return appFunc;
        }
    }


}
```

**The code flow  when I try to access localhost:8080**

**Flow:**

**Enters ->First Middleware**

1. `IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);`
2. `await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1> Middleware:1 ->  Hello from
   X1</h1>"); // Response Sent to browser`
3. `await next.Invoke(environment);`

**Enters -> Second Middleware**

4. `IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);`
5. `await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1> Middleware:2 ->  Hello from
   X2</h1>");// Response Sent to browser`
6. `await next.Invoke(environment);`

**Enters (Back to Calling Method) -> First Middleware**

7. `await next.Invoke(environment);`
8. Exits -> FirstMiddleWare

**Re-Enters ->First Middleware**

9. `IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);`
10. `await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1> Middleware:1 ->  Hello from
     X1</h1>"); // No Response Sent to browser`
11. `await next.Invoke(environment);`

**Re-Enters -> Second Middleware**

12. `IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(environment);`
13. `await context.Response.WriteAsync("<h1> Middleware:2 ->  Hello from
          X2</h1>");// No Response Sent to browser`
14. `await next.Invoke(environment);`

**Re-Enters (Back To Calling Method) -> First Middleware**

15. `await next.Invoke(environment);`
16. Exits -> FirstMiddleWare

**Execution Stops**
My question is why does it traverse again Steps 9 and 16?

and add to it, even though Step 9 and 16 are traversed , response does not change. So I am guessing it is doing some post condition check there.

**  Edit - 1 **

Added All steps traversed to make it more clear( added steps 9 to 16)

Comment: Please narrow down your question making it better aligned with the title. It's too broad and looks more like a request for code review. Thanks and regards,

Comment: The question seems ok to me, and it sure is odd!

Comment: Seems like the "next" of Second Middleware should be null or something equivalent to it

Comment: Do you actually see the Middeware:1 Hello twice in the page?

Comment: @TheMar I only see Middleware:1 once in the output.

Comment: Also, in stepping through the code, VS actually goes through each middleware section twice, printing the text into the webpage the first time. So there is steps 10, 11, 12.

Comment: There's something wrong with your code (i.e. what you're showing isn't what's running), it won't do what you're seeing. Possibly do a clean and rebuild.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee I see it on my end, he isn't talking about the html output, but what you see if you step through VS debugger

Comment: @tofutim- you are right there is steps 10,11,12.  I would have expected the code to exit at step 7

Comment: @tofutim - The response(html) is not sent twice. Only once.

Comment: @Collin Dauphinee - I had done code cleaning and done rebuilds before I posted. I even created a new solution and tried it again but with flow remains same.

Comment: @tofutim- I updated my question with rest of the flow steps

Comment: I don't think it is actually running the code when it goes through the second time. Maybe it is just a figment of VS.

Comment: @tofutim - What I am afraid of is , if I do start creating my own Middleware and if I have 10 of those, it loop through all of the Middleware again ( i just tried with 3 middle ware and it did just that). I think  as you said it may just be the way VS does something ( may be calling dispose :-))

Comment: But why would you ever have 10 middlewares?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104678/discussion-between-tofutim-and-themar).

Answer (score 1):

Steps 9 to 16 are traversed because of an automatic second request you get from the browser for the [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). If you pay attention to the context.Request.Path you will notice that the first round through the middleware is for "/" and the second for "/favicon.ico". Actually the behavior depends on the browser you are using to make the request. I've tested with the most resent version of a couple of browsers and with Webkit browsers (Chrome and Opera) plus IE i always get a request for the favicon. With FF i do get it just the first time and it's being cached. And with Edge - it's not been requested at all.